# sizeof array elements in C

Tags: c, arrays

In `C`, **array elements are treated as pointers**. So the expression `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` becomes `sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int)` which results in `1` then why the following program give output is `12 11`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            int n1, n2;
            char arr1[] = "Hello World";
            char arr2[] = {'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d'};
            n1 = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
            n2 = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
            printf("n1 = %d\nn2 = %d\n", n1, n2);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *"In C, array elements are treated as pointers. So the expression sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) becomes sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int)"* where did you learn these falsehoods?

Comment: @Kninnug please see : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-c-treats-array-parameters-as-pointers/

Comment: @Anjan: `sizeof` is operator, not a function.

Comment: @Anjan, that page talks about array **parameters**, which your code doesn't have.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski, Kninnug Thank you very much.

Comment: `arr1` has null-terminator(`\0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> array elements are treated as pointers

It is not a true. Arrays are **NOT** pointers. But they decay to pointers to first element when are passed to functions. And `sizeof(array)` is the number of bytes that whole array occupies.

Answer (score 0):

> In C, array elements are treated as pointers.

False . Array decays to pointer when passed to function . But you dont have any function to which array is being passed as parameter (*totally unrelated stuff*).

`sizeof` operator is one of exceptions. `sizeof` will give you the size array occupies in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

To make the [Serhio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490757/4833281) clearer it's important to note `sizeof()` is an operator and not a function as said before by Grzegorz on his comment. It means its evaluantion is made in compile-time, but what does it means?

Once `arr1` or `arr2` are declared in that way the compiler knows its size before execution starts and than `sizeof(arr1)` will be converted to `sizeof(char[12])` (it includes `\0` char at the end) and `sizeof(arr2)` to `sizeof(char[11])`, which results in 12 and 11.

As it's made in compile-time the compiler knows they must be handled as arrays and not pointers by the `sizeof()` operator, what is completely different to **dynamically allocated arrays**, which are allocated in execution-time and `sizeof()` will operates over a normal char pointer size (architecture dependent: it may be 4 bytes on 32bits systems or 8 bytes on 64bits).

Comment: With `int n; scanf("%d", &n); int a[n]; printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);`, the size of `a` is not computed at compile time but at run time.  The result is not necessarily 1.

Comment: @chux what I meant by dinamically allocated was using `malloc()`, and than dividing the result by `sizeof(<element_type>)`, as @Anjan pointed on his question, but indeed the result will be 1 just if `element_type` is `int`, sorry, I'll fix it. And in your code you need to be careful: if you swap `scanf()` call with the `a[n]` declaration the `sizeof()` will compile but will result in wrong values (0 for example). When I need something like that I prefer to use `malloc()`. I prefer the recommendations from C89 about declaring every variable at the beginning, before any function calls.

Comment: `int a[n]` is dynamically allocated array and is a counter example to this answer.  The array is declared, yet the compiler does not know it size.  The result of `sizeof a` is determined at run-time - not compile time.  The result is the size of the array, not the size of a pointer.

Comment: @chux I think you are using the "dynamic allocation" concept as "run-time", aren't you? As far as I know they are different things. `int a[n]` is an "automatic" array and not "dynamic", for instance, when you use `int a[n]` the stack will holds its value and not the heap and `a` can't be reallocated anymore. There are other differences yet, take a look at: [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_3.html#SEC18). So yor example isn't a counter example of my explanation about "dynamic allocated arrays".

Comment: "when you use `int a[n]` the stack will holds its value and not the heap" --> maybe, maybe not.  C does not specify that nor stack nor heap - those are unspecified implementation details.  C does not specify  "_dynamically_ allocated".  This differs from your GCC reference.  If we  limit ourselves to GCC world, your answer is better defined.  My comments reflect C in general.

Comment: Disagree about "should suppose ... standard implementation of almost C compilers nowadays".  I regularly use non-gcc compilers in my work as do many other colleagues. Some using Harvard architecture that do not follow your "stack" "heap".  Research the embedded world where C is very popular and run C code even without an OS.  Perhaps your experience is wider than mine?